# I'm regent for my king, now what?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am an 'independent count' (ie my direct liege is the King) in the Kingdom of Lombardy. The honorary title *designated regent* should give me a positive modifier with my king (+10), and probably prestige.

However, my liege, the King of Lombardy, went into hiding and so I am acting as regent.

[image: becoming regent]

From regencies I've had I am aware that one's regent has to agree with decision/actions- sending money, declaring war, etc.

[image: regent]

The [wiki page for regency](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Regency) deals mainly with the issue of selecting and having an AI character regent. It does have to say the following:

> Regents may:
>
> - face competition from other courtiers/direct vassals for control over the regency, including being replaced.
> - embezzle money from the ruler
> - donate to charity on behalf of the ruler (ruler loses wealth but gains piety)
> - steal demesne holdings from the ruler, if the ruler has at least 5
> - lower crown authority or tribal organization
> - attempt to kill the underage ruler
> - attempt to declare the underage ruler insane, imprison the ruler, and eventually steal the throne

But it isn't clear if any or all of these apply to a *player* regent.

**What powers, effects or decisions does being regent give me?**

---

<sup>Note: I don't have [Conclave DLC](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Conclave), but I am interested in effects that are in play either with Conclave or without.</sup>

Comment: I never played as a regent before, but the general philosophy of CKII is that players and NPCs have the same options available to them. Have you checked the Intrigue screen?

Comment: Good point, will check! I've not had any events in the number of years I've been regent - compare with eg being a Steward/Chancellor etc or guardian.

Comment: @Philipp I checked, and there seem to be no decisions or plots in the intrigue screen relating to being regent. Good thought though!

Comment: As with most paradox games, the AI screws with you when they become regents but you can't screw with the AI.

Comment: @Xander Hah! Well, I'll just have to screw them in other ways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get any powers or any decision to carry out any of those things.

However there are events for all of those which can be triggered depending on a number of factors and sheer dumb luck. At the same time, your charge can get the event to charge at you with a wooden horse and kill you by pushing you off the balcony.

You can find the full list of events [here](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Regency_events). You can then proceed to looking them up in the events file and find the triggering conditions for each one of them.

Comment: I figured as much but I couldn't find anything definitive, good tip on the events :)